# One integral, two solutions?

Tags: calculus

I ran into an interesting integral problem: the indefinite integral of $\int \frac{dx}{a^2 x^2 - b^2}$. I can do a hyperbolic trig substitution and get that the result is $- \frac{1}{ab}\operatorname{arctanh}\frac{ax}{b}$ and Mathematica agrees with this. However, in some integral tables, I was able to find a result that is $\frac{1}{2ab} \ln{ \frac{ax - b}{ax + b}}$.

Both functions have the same derivative. However, they don't seem to be equal (I've plotted them and even expressed the inverse hyperbolic tangent as a logarithm). Can anyone explain what I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps they differ... by a constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both those integrals are correct, but over different domains. At least, if we confine all the functions to real values.

The arctanh works in the interval $(-\frac ba, \frac ba)$, the ln for $(-\infty, -\frac ba) \cup (\frac ba, \infty)$ (if both $a$ and $b$ are positive).

Remember, $\mathrm{arctanh}(u)$ has the domain $(-1,1)$. $\ln(u)$ has the domain $(0,\infty)$ and $\frac{ax-b}{ax+b}>0$ for $x<-\frac ba<$ or $\frac ba<x$ if both $a$ and $b$ are positive.

I suppose the full indefinite integral is a combination of those two given answers. (See below for an alternative.) Or, we could allow complex results for either arctanh or ln; then either one would do. Smart graphers like Geogebra apparently allow the complex values, since the derivatives take up the entire (twice-punctured) real line. Dumber graphers, like my TI-Nspire CX, stick to real values and show the reduced domains. Here are some graphs from an emulated TI-Nspire CX. In these graphs, $a=b=1$ for definiteness.

[image]

[image]

**ADDED LATER:**

For completeness, I should mention that there is another, easy way to get an integral that gives the derivative over the entire twice-punctured real numbers. Namely, put an absolute value inside the ln function, so we get

$$\frac{1}{2ab} \ln{\left|\frac{ax - b}{ax + b}\right|}$$

This makes sense, since some tables of integrals (such as my CRC 13th Student Edition) assumes that all integrals with $\ln(\cdot)$ in them actually mean $\ln(|\cdot|)$.

See the final graph to see the result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not think about complex arguments. This actually came up in a physics problem, so I guess you have to be savvy about thinking about the correct domain. It's a free-fall problem with drag proportional to the square of velocity, so you should be able to deduce the "correct" form of the answer based on which function ends up giving you correct limiting behavior (i.e. terminal velocity).

Comment: @Ron: See the addition to my answer. This gives you one discontinuous solution to your integral that covers the entire natural domain. But of course, it matters if the starting velocity is above or below the terminal velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compute
$$\frac1{2ab}\ln\frac{ax-b}{ax+b}+\frac1{ab}\text{arctanh}\frac{ax}b$$

You should eventually obtain a constant.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get 2 different-looking answers depending on how you integrate, but as hardmath says, as long as they vary by a constant, it doesn't matter.  For an indefinite integral,  you have to "+ C" part, and the difference in C between the two forms can make up the difference.  For a definite integral, you are doing a subtraction, so that the constant difference drops out.

The simplest example of this is 
$$\int \sin x \cos x dx$$
If you let $u=\sin x$, you get $1/2 \sin^2 x +C$.  If you let $u=\cos x$, you get -$1/2 \cos^2 x+C$.  But since $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, these 2 answers differ my a constant, and it turns out to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

$\text{arctanh} z = \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1+z}{1-z}$ and $\text{arctanh} (-z) = -\text{arctanh} (z)$

In your case $z=-\frac{ax}{b}$ and you are done.

The general solution to an indefinite integral always has an additive constant, so there are infinitely many different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a second problem with this integral, besides the two antiderivatives differing by a constant as many users have pointed out here. One definition of hyperbolic arctangent is $$\text{arctanh}({x}) = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)$$ hence $$\frac{-1}{ab}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{ax}{b}\right) = \frac{-1}{2ab}\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{ax}{b}}{1-\frac{ax}{b}} \right) \\ =  \frac{1}{2ab}\ln\left(\frac{1-\frac{ax}{b}}{1+\frac{ax}{b}} \right) \\ = \frac{1}{2ab}\ln\left(\frac{b-ax}{b+ax} \right)$$ and $$\frac{1}{2ab}\ln\left(\frac{b-ax}{b+ax} \right) \neq \frac{1}{2ab}\ln\left(\frac{ax-b}{b+ax} \right)$$ So the incorrect order of terms in the numerator of the argument of the natural log may be contributing to the confusion as well.

Comment: You're right that your two final values are inequal - but it _is_ in fact the case that the two differ by a constant.  You've got terms of the form $\ln y$ and $\ln(-y)$, and the latter is $\ln((-1)\cdot y)= \ln(-1)+\ln(y) = i\pi+\ln y$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki good point. I will rephrase this answer then

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for the answer. I had not thought about adding a complex constant.